# Excel VBA for Macbook hide ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ribbon

I have an Excel spreadsheet that runs on my Windows PC and have been easily able to use VBA to completely hide the Toolbar ribbon. I have not been able to find a way for doing this using VBA on my Macbook Air.

I have carried out several searches on the Internet and have not yet found a solution.

Is this just a limitation of VBA for Macbooks or is there a way of achieving this using VBA? See screenshots attached illustrating the difference between Macbook Air and PC.

[Macbook Air](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTG2r.png)

[Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6k7S.png)

Current code:

```
With Application
    .DisplayFullScreen = True
    .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
    .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
    .DisplayFormulaBar = False
End With
```

Comment: And how does your solution for windows look?

Comment: Th PC screenshot is Windows. I have amended it now to read Windows 11 to avoid confusion.

Comment: How does your solution per code look like?

Comment: This is my vba code for Windows:- With Application
       .DisplayFullScreen = True
       .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
       .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
       .DisplayFormulaBar = False
    End With

Comment: Please put the code in your question, much easier to read that way!

Comment: The code is already in the question. It is as clear as it can be. Do you have a solution to my question?

Comment: I'm afraid not, never tried Office for Mac. The code is in the question because I helped you put it there! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not realise you had put the code in the question, I am new to this forum.